# variables in curl api requests

Tags: bash, api, curl

I have been playing around with a api and I am able to request data and parse the json response.
However, I am using variables in my requests and those are giving me issues.
If the variable contains no spaces then all works great, but if there are spaces then I get failures.

This is how I am doing it

```
search="string with space"
curl -s 'https://apiurl.com' \
> -d 'search "'$search'";' \
> -H 'user-key: xxxxxxxxxxx' \
> -H 'Accept: application/json'
[
  {
    "title": "Syntax Error",
    "status": 400,
    "cause": "Mismatched input, double check your input. Common cause is sending \\\" instead of \"."
  }
]
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?
If I use the string with spaces in the request, not using the variable, then it works no problem.

Comment: Try `-d 'search "'"$search"'";'`

Comment: Thank you. That works.

Answer (score 2):

Classic case of the QUOTATION-MARK-19 virus. :)

Just replace `'search "'$search'";'` with `'search "'"$search"'";'`
All you were missing was an extra double quote to allow for the variable expansion of `$search`

```
search="string with space"
curl -s 'https://apiurl.com' \
> -d 'search "'"$search"'";' \
> -H 'user-key: xxxxxxxxxxx' \
> -H 'Accept: application/json'
[
  {
    "title": "Syntax Error",
    "status": 400,
    "cause": "Mismatched input, double check your input. Common cause is sending \\\" instead of \"."
  }
]
```